# Plotly-Dash box plot inside Card component

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a box plot inside a Plotly-Dash Card component and then when I change the dropdown, I get another card added inside the already existing card. How can I have the existing figure update instead of adding a new card please.

```
from dash import Dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash_bootstrap_templates import load_figure_template
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from dash import Dash, html, dcc
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def render(app: Dash):
    @app.callback(Output("box-plot", "children"),Input("country-dropdown", "value"))
    def update_boxplot(country: str) -> html.Div:
        fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Box(y=np.random.randn(50) - 1),go.Box(y=np.random.randn(50) + 1)])
        return html.Div(dbc.Card([dbc.CardHeader("Box plot"), dbc.CardBody(dcc.Graph(figure=fig), id="box-plot")]))

    return html.Div(id="box-plot")

def getFigureRow(app:Dash):
    return dbc.Row([dbc.Col([render(app)], width=12)], align='center')

def getDropdownRow(app: Dash):
    return html.Div(
        children=[dcc.Dropdown(id="country-dropdown",options=["DE", "FR", "ES"],value="DE",multi=False)]
    )

def create_layout(app: Dash):
    print("create_layout(...) called")
    return html.Div([
        html.H1(app.title),
        dbc.Tabs([
            dbc.Tab(
                dbc.Card(
                    dbc.CardBody([
                        getDropdownRow(app),
                        getFigureRow(app),
                    ]), body=True), label="Visualize")
        ])
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.DARKLY])
    load_figure_template("darkly")
    app.title = "Dummy"
    app.layout = create_layout(app)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Resolved - render needs to return html.div and not a dbc.Card. Moved card to getFigureRow.

Comment: when you have the chance, consider adding your answer and accepting it – this will help anyone else who has the same question as you in the future since people don't often look in the comments – thanks!